# Is there a convention for indicating a quantity's units in Python code?

Tags: python, comments

*Please note that I'm coming at this from the point of view of **human readability** rather than informing the program itself of the units in use.*

---

I'm working on a project at the moment with strong links to **mechanical engineering**, and one of the issues that has come up a couple of times is that it's not clear from my code what **units** a given quantity - usually a constant, but the criticism could be extended to some variables as well - is measured in.

At the moment, I'm doing this:

```py
length = 28
# ^^^ measured in mm ^^^
```

But this feels hacky and a bit ugly. I could do this:

```py
length = 28 # <<< measured in mm
```

That looks better, but I had it drummed into me at university that inline comments are Satanic, and it's a prejudice I'm having trouble letting go of. (Although, having said that, I was only taught C and Java in university, where the pitfalls of inline comments are more obvious. Are inline comments acceptable in Python?)

Is there some **useful convention** dictating how to indicate a quantity's units in a clear and elegant fashion? Or am I on my own on this one?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/units/

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/measurement/

Comment: be sure if you are using python, in 99% cases you will never encounter any single problem. enjoy python 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On top of inline comments which are fine;

***Option 1 : Variable name***

You can set a variable name, yet it may fault if you calculate and change it later - so it better suits constants.

```
LENGTH_IN_METERS = 3
```

***Option 2: [`pint`](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)***

Pint is a nice library that lets you keep up with the variable measurement unit.

e.g.

```
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
3 * ureg.meter + 4 * ureg.cm
<Quantity(3.04, 'meter')>
```

***Option 3: [`python-measurement`](https://python-measurement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)***

Easily use and manipulate unit-aware measurement objects in Python.

e.g.

Converting other measures into kilometers:

```
from measurement.measures import Distance
distance = Distance(mi=10).km
```

Answer (score 2):

Inline comments are certainly acceptable in Python, but I'm not sure there is a single accepted way for annotating units. You might want to attach the information to the variable name, e.g. `length_mm = 28`. Or build a proper class or namedtuple, e.g.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Length = namedtuple('Length', ['value', 'unit'])
>>> ln = Length(28, 'mm')
>>> ln
Length(value=28, unit='mm')
>>> ln.value
28
>>> ln.unit
'mm'
```